# How to refresh ConcurrentMapCache periodically in Spring 4?

Tags: java, spring, caching

If I am using `@Cashable` annotation to cache the results using a `ConcurrentMapCacheManager`, then how would I periodically refresh the cache in Spring 4.3.5?

It looks like Ehcache provides some implementation and it depends on the backing store, but I would like to understand in case I am not using any external cache backing store.

One option I am thinking about is to periodically call a method, but what implementation will go into that method? How will I collect and call all those cachable methods again?

It would be great to look at some examples.

Answer (score 4):

There is no direct spring abstraction for periodic cache refresh, you can also verify [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html) from spring docs, but, you can achieve the same with the simple scheduled method using `@Scheduled` like below:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${YOUR_CRON_INTERVAL}")
@CacheEvict(value = "yourCache", allEntries = true)
public void resetAllEntries() {
    //write the code to repopulate the cache again here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll have to be implemented this for each cache, right?

Comment: yes, you are right, implement the same for each cache